# Разбиение на секции

Tags: html, css

Как разбить на секции html code как на фотке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Осталось только покрасить секции в нужные цвета

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
}
ul li {
  margin-right: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sections</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section>Секция</section>
  <section>Секция</section>
  <section>Секция</section>
  <section>Секция</section>
  <section>Секция</section>
  <section>Секция</section>
  <footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#!"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!"><span>Shop</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!"><span>Delivery</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!"><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну чтобы ещё разные цвета у секции были, нужно сделать им классы и тогда можно назначить разные цвета.